# How does one calculate the increase calorific needs of weightlifters?

Tags: weightlifting, diet, olympic

Calorie expenditure from weightlifting is hard to estimate, but additionally, weightlifting imposes additional metabolic demands on the body that burn more calories.

For example: given a 300 rep per week olympic lifting program at a given average intensity of 85% at 90kg (example day shown); how many additional calories do you burn?

[image]

In essence, I'm asking given the inputs of: intensity, weights lifted, body weight, and total reps, is there a rough formula for additional calorific expenditure?

If not, how do high level Olympic weightlifting coaches determine calorific needs?

This is not a question about the energy expenditure of specific lifts, I know that’s irrelevant here.

Comment: I got a really negative response from Reddit’s fit when I asked this.  Basically saying it’s not ever important and only BMR matters.  Which sounds like BS to me.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to know? The majority of calorie calculations are, at best, very rough estimates used only for guidance.

Comment: I want to know because I'm trying to get into a weight class.  Most weightloss advice is for detrained people.  My calorie intake has been a little extreme <3500 a day and following the orthodoxy of eating TDEE - 500 probably isn't the best thing for me.  In a typical day, I walk 10'000 steps, cycle 40mins and spend 90 minutes doing a strength routine.  I've gained some weight this year, less than 4kg, but that's not that much when I eat 4000 calories regularly.

Comment: The reason I want to know estimation formulas is because I've already disregarded the common orthodoxy on what to eat.  No one on a weightloss form will suggest eating 2500 calories a day to lose weight - but in the last week, I've lost a kilo from that diet.

Comment: If I can estimate how much I'm burning through weight training, it will help me plan my meals better for peak performance.

Comment: (N.B I know that a weekly scale reading isn't necessarily an accurate measurement, but I feel that I've lost weight; waist is smaller, more definition etc).

Comment: @Rol I mean based on what you said, we can estimate your daily calorie expenditure to be between 3500-4000. So eating 2500 would yield about 1 KG per week for you.  It's a pretty aggressive weightloss strategy but it'll work.  TDEE includes your training, and if you're consistent with it then it's not special. It's just your lifestyle.  TDEE = BMR + Training + NEAT + TEF. If you were to just stop training, then your TDEE would go down in relation.

Comment: @Rol how exactly do you intend to use this data to "help you plan your meals better for peak performance"? Do you intend to use it to adjust your intake to have more calories on training days and less on non-training days?

Comment: Yes.  That’s what I plan to do.

Comment: Just eat more on training days and discount those calories on non-training, as long as your total weekly calories are the same you'll still going to be in deficit. So at 2500/day you're at 17500/week, distribute it daily as you prefer. Your weight might fluctuate more on a daily basis too (water retention, etc)

Answer (score 5):

**You don't calculate the increased caloric needs of weightlifters, because there's no situation in which you'd need that information.**

> If not, how do high level Olympic weightlifting coaches determine calorific needs?

Same as with anyone else - observe what the athlete is currently eating, and make adjustments to that based on the desired outcome. Let's say you have a lifter who you want to move up from the 73kg to 81kg class. They're currently 72kg and you want them to gain 8kg in 9 months. So you have them track their food intake for a few weeks, determining that they're currently eating about 3200 kcal/day. You get them to increase their intake to 3500 kcal/day, and observe from there how their bodyweight changes.

At no point in this process does the amount of energy they're burning during training (measured separately to their total daily energy expenditure) need to be known.

Comment: Right. That’s the practical way of doing things.

Comment: But are you seriously telling me we have no idea how much energy is expended weight training?

Comment: If you have the data of what Olympic athletes are eating and their diets, surely there’s enough data to make a rough calculation of their energy expenditure w.r.t work, weight, intensity, and body weight.